# File Browse with Ionic Framework

Tags: android, ios, file, cordova, browser

I would like to ask you all a question. I have to create a file browser with Ionic Framework and I successful created following Nic post:

[www.airpair.com - ionic-file-browser-app](https://www.airpair.com/ionic-framework/posts/ionic-file-browser-app)

I've also added these lines to config.xml:

```
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal"/>
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility"/>
```

All work well, but I would like that android behaves like iOS, in fact iOS root directory is the app's document root, instead the Android root directory is

```
/storage/emulated/0
```

The question is. How can I set my personal root directory for Android? Like this, for example:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<my-app-ID>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access directory of android apk, you should store file in sdcard or in www dir. If you want files removed when app is uninstalled store them in www.

Comment: Thank you. I will check.